# БП трещит при высоком количестве фпс

Tags: пк

Понимаю что прозвучит возможно дико, но блок питания трещит именно при высоком ФПС а не при большой нагрузке, когда прогоняю комп в FurMark + CPU Burner и нагрузка на видеокарту и процессор 100% то никаких звуков от БП нет, так же в тяжелых играх, во время игры все стабильно без всяких шумов, однако в Minecraft в плоском мире если закопаться в ямочку, то БП начинает трещать, однако стоит лишь ограничить количество кадров как проблема пропадает. Есть ли этому какое то обьяснение не может же быть проблема в том что не хватает питания?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что данный вопрос не подходит под тематику данного форума.

Comment: Как относится ФПС к блоку питания?) Видеокарта с питанием от БП?) и еслиб была перегрузка БП, то был бы не треск, а пищание) а вообще вопрос стоит закрыть, так как дать на него вразумительный ответ без диагностики нереально) даже не могу представить что там может трещать

Comment: о, а это уже интересно) если действительно источник треска локализовали верно, в первую очередь я бы пожалуй глянул линии доп питания для видео карты и цп. если есть свободные такие же, можно попробовать в.карту и\или цп перекинуть на них. но вообще, хоть что то делать с бп который действительно хоть иногда именно **трещит**, крайней рискованная затея - можете спалить что либо. треском обычно сопровождаются искрящие короткие замыкания... если нет навыков ремонта силовой электроники, единственное что на мой взгляд тут стоит делать - заменить бп или хотя бы сдать в ремонт, от греха подальше.